Table actions not firing
I have a table function in a custom Filament page:
I have initialized the page like this:

<?php

namespace App\Filament\App\Resources\OIPRequestResource\Pages;

use App\Filament\App\Resources\OIPRequestResource;
use Filament\Resources\Pages\Page;
use Filament\Tables\Contracts\HasTable;
use Filament\Forms\Contracts\HasForms;
use Filament\Tables\Table;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use App\Models\OIPRequest;
use Filament\Tables\Filters\SelectFilter;
use Filament\Tables\Filters\Filter;
use Filament\Resources\Pages\ListRecords\Tab;
use Filament\Tables\Columns\TextColumn;
use Filament\Tables\Columns\IconColumn;
use Filament\Tables\Concerns\InteractsWithTable;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Filament\Forms\Components\Select;
use Filament\Forms\Concerns\InteractsWithForms;
use Filament\Resources\Concerns\HasTabs;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Filament\Tables\Actions\Action;
use Filament\Actions\Concerns\InteractsWithActions;
use Filament\Actions\Contracts\HasActions;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Filament\Tables\Actions\ActionGroup;

class IncentiveOverview extends Page implements HasTable, HasForms, HasActions
{
    use InteractsWithTable;
    use InteractsWithForms;
    use InteractsWithActions;
    use HasTabs;
    
    //...

And my table like below:
public function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
        ->query(function (): Builder {
                return $this->getIncentiveRequests()->groupBy(['branch_id', 'department_id']);
            })
            ->modifyQueryUsing($this->modifyQueryWithActiveTab(...))
            ->columns([
                TextColumn::make('department.name')
                    ->label('Department')
                    ->sortable(),
                TextColumn::make('gp')
                    ->label('GP')
                    ->money('eur', true)
                    ->state(function ($record) {
                        return $this->calculateGP($record);
                    })
                    ->sortable(),
            ])
            ->actions([
                Action::make('view_incentive_details')
                    ->label('View Incentive Details')
                    ->action(function ($record) {
                        dd($record);
                    })
                ]);
    }

Then, the blade view is looking like this:
<x-filament::page>
    <div class="flex flex-col gap-4">
        <x-filament-panels::resources.tabs />
        <div class="relative">
            {{ $this->table }}
        </div>
         <x-filament-actions::modals />
    </div>
</x-filament::page>

When I try to trigger the view_incentive_details, I would for now, expect that it would just dd the $record, however, when I click it, a spinner is just shown briefly:


Is there any output in your console when firing the action?

No, nothing is written to the console either

any relevant javascript console errors? what about php error log? is the http response 200?

First of ALL, clear the cache using this cammand
php artisan clear:cache

then update the Action section of Table
->action(function ($record) {
Log::info('View Incentive Details', ['record' => $record]);
Notification::make()
    ->title('Action Triggered')
    ->body('The record has been processed.')
    ->success()
    ->send();
})

This is Filament's notification system with Laravel logs.
after running this code update, check Telescope logs section.
In case If you don't use telescope. By default, Laravel stores log files in the storage/logs directory of your project. The default log file is named laravel.log

oliverbj
->please add bellow code to your code :
use Filament\Tables\Actions\Action;


I think you are using wrong import for making action that's why it's not working correctly.


I'm already using the Table namespace for the Action. Unfortunately, same result :(. I have updated my question so it now includes namespaces.

hi,
can i get your code so that i can reflect it my system?
